# Check if bluetooth device has mic Android

Tags: android, bluetooth

In android,im trying to get the bluetooth paired devices list and after that,check capability if it has mic in the headset.

is it possible to find it in android?

Set pairedDevices = bluetoothAdapter.getBondedDevices();

```
        for (BluetoothDevice device : pairedDevices) {

            BluetoothClass bluetoothClass = device.getBluetoothClass();



            if (bluetoothClass != null) {
                int deviceClass = bluetoothClass.getDeviceClass();



                if (deviceClass == Device.AUDIO_VIDEO_WEARABLE_HEADSET
                        || deviceClass == Device.AUDIO_VIDEO_CAR_AUDIO
                        || deviceClass == Device.AUDIO_VIDEO_HANDSFREE
                        || deviceClass == Device.AUDIO_VIDEO_UNCATEGORIZED


                        ) {
                           }
                       }
                  }
```

How can i know from the device class if it has mic capability ,or user can talk from device if the device class returned is Device.AUDIO_VIDEO_WEARABLE_HEADSET ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use check bluetooth device's class:

```
private void getDeviceClass(BluetoothDevice device) {
  int btClass = device.getBluetoothClass().getDeviceClass();
  // check your device class; class constants are listed in the Reference link 
  // AUDIO_VIDEO_MICROPHONE, AUDIO_VIDEO_HANDSFREE,
  // or even PHONE_* may match your requirements
}
```

Reference: [BluetoothClass.Device](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/bluetooth/BluetoothClass.Device.html#AUDIO_VIDEO_MICROPHONE)

Comment: Ive edited my original question,problem is,in bose audio speaker with bluetooth support,Device Class returns Device.AUDIO_VIDEO_WEARABLE_HEADSET.But bose audio speaker has no mic capability.

Im developing a dialer application which should not route the audio to speaker if device has no mic capability.

Comment: this [app](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.webalis.bluetoothMicTest&hl=en) records a small piece of audio & check whether the audio has volume. Maybe you can do similar logic.

Comment: dont think is a good solution,in my dialer application,when call connects,ill need to decide where to route the audio and take headset  mic input or devices mic input.

user might not talk in that case audio wouldnt have any volume also.

determining the capability of mi should there,as the phones default dialer application does this,when there is no mic in headset,it doesnt route the audio to headset.